# Angular Firebase observable not updating content

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database

I am using angular and firebase to create a simply chat component. When I create a simply observable in my component, I can add a new document to the collection with the appropriate ID, but nothing happens. The observer does not react to the updated data.

When I reload the page, it reflects the additional data. However, my expectation was that changes to the collection that met the requirements would be reflected automatically. Thanks

Component:

```
ngOnInit(): void
{

    this._chatService.getConversations()
        .subscribe(result => {

            var tempArray = [];
            var docData;
            result.forEach((doc) => {
                docData=doc.data();
                docData.uid=doc.id;
                //console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
                tempArray.push(docData);
            });
            this.conversations = tempArray;

            console.log('The conversations in the chats are ...');
            console.log(this.conversations);
        });

}
```

Service:

```
/**
 * Get conversations
 *
 */
getConversations( ):Observable<any> {

    let userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));
    console.log('participantId of '+userData.uid);
    return this.afs.collection('convParticipants', ref => ref.where('participantId', '==', userData.uid)).get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like getConversations is acting as a basic get, so you call it once on init and then the observable is completed.

What I would do is make some sort of observable or trigger in your code to either re-call the `getConversations()` method call (maybe an RxJS Interval: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/interval) or a manual refresh button.

Other potential reasons (assuming the  `getConversations()` method acts as a true observable ..
It could happen outside of angulars change detection. Try adding ...

```
 constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
...
...
 this.conversations = tempArray;
this.ref.detectChanges();
```

Other than that I would log to see if the observable gets triggered/what the return value is for the getConversations() method.